# Shopify theme editor + Vue3.x: how to pass new section setting value to Vue app?

Tags: shopify, vuejs3, shopify-template

I am trying to integrate Vue3.x with Shopify theme editor. Now I can make the Vue app work in theme editor. However, when I try to change the Add to bundle button color in section, the button color cannot be updated immediately.

So I try to listen to the shopify:section:select event. But the function remountVueApp() is always showing the old {{ section.settings.button_color }} value. So I don't know how to get pass the updated value from section.settings to Vue app. How can it be done?

When I press Save button, the section setting can be saved and new button color is shown.

The screenshot is showing the debug message after I change the button color in theme editor

[image: Shopify theme editor]

```
<!-- This will only render in the theme editor -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/mitt/dist/mitt.umd.js"></script>
<script>
  function remountVueApp() {
    console.log('listen to shopify theme editor re-render. Render app to respond to DOM update');
    vueApp = createMyApp();
    console.log('button_color 2 = {{ section.settings.button_color }}');
    buttonColor = '{{ section.settings.button_color }}';
             
    vueApp.component('product-card', productCard) 
    vm = vueApp.mount('#byobApp') 
  }

  const emitter = window.mitt();
  emitter.on('shopify:section:select', remountVueApp);

  const themeEventHandler = (event) => {
    console.log(event.detail.load)
    if (event.detail.load) {
      // emit a generic version
      console.log('button_color 1 = {{ section.settings.button_color }}');
      emitter.emit(`${event.type}`, event);
    }
  };

  // these are custom events emitted by the Shopify section editor
  // we are hooking them up to our Vue event dispatcher
  document.addEventListener('shopify:section:select', themeEventHandler);  
</script>
```

Comment: it thinks you don't need to add any liquid code to the JS file, use it into sections in liquid code it will automatically change, once you update any value inside the sections.

Comment: Yes, I tried to define a test class in the <style> tag. The class includes section settings. Now it works. Thanks

Comment: glad to know it works for you.